# Use PVlib in 1-axis [vertical] and 2-axis PV arrays

Tags: python, pvlib

I would like to know if it is possible to use PVlib to make predictions for 1-axis (**vertical**) and 2-axis PV arrays. Despite not very common, these PV plants have a big presence in some countries and it would be great to make use of PVlib to make the predictions.

I have been able to get the POA Irradiances for both cases:

- 1-axis (vertical): I obtained the irradiance multiplying the direct normal irradiance by the angle of incidence projection. Method `pvlib.irradiance.aoi_projection`.
- 2-axis: The PV array surface is always perpendicular to the sun beam. Therefore the irradiance on the plane of array is the direct normal irradiance (dni).

But I got stuck when trying to convert these irradiances into PV power! Since this type of tracking systems are not taken into account in PVlib, I'm not sure of which would be the best approach to get the PV power. So any help in which steps would you recommend me will be appreciated!

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [`pvlib.tracking.singleaxis`](http://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/pvlib.tracking.singleaxis.html#pvlib.tracking.singleaxis) function allows you to specify axis tilt. Presumably you can set the axis tilt to 90 degrees and get reasonable results for vertical systems, but you'd have to follow the referenced literature to know if/how it's been validated at that orientation. I've never compared it to data in that orientation.

I'm a bit confused by your question, though. If you already have the POA irradiance and AOI then you're ready to move on to calculating power using the standard PV models (single diode, SAPM, PVWatts): http://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pv-modeling